# Can't connect to my database, Error is unexpected '['

Tags: php, connectivity

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("rohan");
$s="select * from black";
$resource=mysql_query($s);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($resource);


            echo "ID: ".row[0]."<br>";
            echo "Name: ".row[1]." ".row[2]."<br>";
            echo "E-mail: ".row[3]."<br>";
            echo "country: ".row[4]."<br>";
            echo "salary: ".row[5]."<br>";
```

I can't connect to my database with this code.   It gives me this error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\rohan\mysql_fetch_row.php on line 9

What is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by not working???

Comment: You should include the exception details and the stack trace in your question

Comment: show this error     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\rohan\mysql_fetch_row.php on line 9

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have merged your error into your post.  I marked it by using >.  Please do not use comments to enhance your post, instead edit it.  Sometimes , it is better to indicate where you have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

You retrieve row not an array, so change your code from:

```
 $row = mysql_fetch_row($resource);
```

to

```
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($resource);
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($resource);
```

to

```
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);
```

done

Answer (score 0):

for this line you don't connect to database:

```
$resource=mysql_query($s);

I think you should replace by this:

  $sql=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("rohan");
  $s="select * from black";
  $resource=mysql_query($s,$sql);
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($resource);
  echo "ID: ".$row[0]."<br>";
  echo "Name: ".$row[1]." ".$row[2]."<br>";
  echo "E-mail: ".$row[3]."<br>";
  echo "country: ".$row[4]."<br>";
  echo "salary: ".$row[5]."<br>";
?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\rohan\mysql_fetch_row.php on line 7

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use `$` for local variables.

Instead

```
echo "ID: ".row[0]."<br>";
```

MUST be

```
echo "ID: ".$row[0]."<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist make sure your query is run correctly.

Second make sure there are some records in assumed table.

I modified your code a bit like below.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("rohan");
$s="select * from black";
$resource=mysql_query($s);
if (!$resource) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($resource);
if (!$row || !is_array($row)) {
    echo 'row is no valid: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

            echo "ID: ".row[0]."<br>";
            echo "Name: ".row[1]." ".row[2]."<br>";
            echo "E-mail: ".row[3]."<br>";
            echo "country: ".row[4]."<br>";
            echo "salary: ".row[5]."<br>";
```